# How does jQuery implement the before method under the hood?

Tags: jquery

How is it possible that we can pass a string with HTML markup to [jQuery's .before](https://api.jquery.com/before/) method and it successfully builds the element? Is there some hidden logic which somehow scans the string and builds it into actual nodes using .createElement? When I tried to find this string to node logic in jQuery I didnt find anything. See below for more details.

The .before method implementation exactly as it is in unminified Jquery 3.6.6 - https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js

[image: Screenshot of the before method declared in jquery]

What I understand from that is that they call .insertBefore method which is vanilla javascript.

But insertBefore requires a node - meaning you have to do document.createElement to create it, documentation below:

```
let insertedNode = parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)
//insertedNode = The node being inserted (the same as newNode)
```

From MDN docs for .insertBefore - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

So how come jQuery lets us call `.before('<p>Test</p>')` and it works even though it looks like jQuery isnt building the node using .createElement?

I was hoping to find something like this code below in jQuery

```
//somehow dynamically get tagName + textValue
var tag = document.createElement(tagName); //'p'
tag.innerText = "textValue //'Test'
```

Which would be utilized by jQuery .before method, but I didnt find anything.

I did find the jQuery.parseHTML function in their code, which is the only function where they dynamically create nodes using createElement, but then this function isnt used by the before method so again, how is the .before method able to take a string HTML as a parameters and successfully convert it to a node when there is no such logic in the implementation?

Comment: "*What I understand from that is that they call .insertBefore method which is vanilla javascript.*" they call `domManip` and pass `arguments` to it. `.insertBefore` is in the callback. Very likely because `domManip` will execute the callback after it's finished parsing the arguments.

Comment: @VLAZ oooh! And then domManip calls buildFragment and it looks like thats what takes care of creating the actual nodes?

Comment: Probably. I've not looked at the code other than what you showed here. I also know that jQuery has its own parsing engine it uses, so it must be something that's called in `domManip`.